# Raspberry Pi Pico Keeps Ejecting

Tags: thonny, raspberry-pi-pico

I've just gotten my Raspberry Pi Pico and am trying to get it ready to accept code. I've tried dragging and dropping MicroPython from the webpage and using Thonny to handle it automatically, but when I do either, it ejects itself and nothing has loaded. I'm trying to do this from a Pi 4. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it (but not on a RaspPI)...  hold the BootSel button on the Pico and *then* plug it in.  A new "disk" should appear to the OS (or on the desktop). Drag the Micropython UF2 file onto the new disk - this installs Micropython on the Pico. The file gets copied, the Pico saves it to flash, and the "disk" ejects itself.

Now, in Thonny, you have to select the correct board (Pico) and the correct serial interface device (/dev/it-depends-on-your-system). The Thonny page has notes for this. At this point, with Micropython, we talk to it over the serial line, not as a disk.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I really does sound as if you are trying to install MicroPython without downloading it and/or to run a MicroPython program without installing the MicroPython system. You first have to install the MicroPython system, download a uf2 file, and only then can you install and run a MicroPython program using Thonny.

Answer (score 0):

Answering here because I had trouble getting mine to work too. In my case, I somehow got my pico into such a state that Mass Storage Device mode would randomly disconnect / eject, often before I could even drag a new UF2 file to the device.

Since I didn't have the time to be successful with drag/drop before the device disconnected, I built and used [`picotool`](https://github.com/raspberrypi/picotool) to push the "nuke memory" UF2 file ([see link here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/raspberry-pi-pico.html#resetting-flash-memory)). (`BOOTSEL` held down, plugin, hit enter on the terminal to run ASAP before the pico disconnects)

I actually had to do this two or three times, but after that it stopped being weird and Mass Storage mode works correctly again; I was able to install the MicroPython UF2 file with the normal drag and drop method and Thonny no longer disconnects.